# Eclipse plug-in development - Multiple workbanches/pages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am developing an eclipse plugin application.

I have the following scenario:

Main application gui will be based on eclipse, a workbench with a page.
In this page there will be a toolbar, menu bar, some views and multiple editor.

Until now the task is standard.

But here is a "twist":  I want to show a popup window (org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog) and in this dialog i want to insert another editor.  In this editor I want to use GEF framework.

Currently I access page like this (which is used by all editors):

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse, especially eclipse 3.x (Helios, Indigo) won't allow editors in dialogs gracefully.  With no IEditorSite (the editor's link to the workbench page) many of the services it uses won't be available, and it might not even start.